# How to upload file from local machine to the browser using python?

Tags: python, html, web, flask, automation

I am using python to upload a file from my local disk to the web browser for an automation work. The folder name is "docs" which is in C directory. Docs folder contains 2 files "textnex.txt" and "safe.txt" so i want "textnext.txt" to upload on a web page. Here is my python code as below:

```
    # os for file management
import os
# Build tuple of (class, file) to turn in
submission_dir = r'C:\Users\Sonu\docs'
dir_list = list(os.listdir(submission_dir))
for directory in dir_list:
    file_list = list(os.listdir(os.path.join(submission_dir, 
directory)))
    if len(file_list) != 0:
        file_tup = (directory, file_list[0])

print(file_tup)
```

When i run this code it is not printing the files. I want textnex.txt to be uploaded on the web page. Have a look at the screenshot for the current result which is very weird to me. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.
[image: Its showing .anaconda and navigator. I am confused]

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is reasonable for the code you show.  It is a single tuple that could well be made up of a directory name and a file name.

The FOR loop assigns a single tuple value to **file_tup** for each non-empty directory - and replaces that value for each succeeding directory.  When you exit from the FOR loop, the value assigned for the last iteration through the FOR loop is all that remains in **file_tup**.

You might want to run a debugger (or put some debug PRINT statements in your code) to monitor the significant variables as your loop runs in order to see exactly what is going on.